# Mysql slow query on huge table

Tags: mysql

I have huge table (about 5 billion rows).

This query takes about 3 minutes on first run. Create temporary table takes almost 3 minutes too. And about 1.5s on another runs.

We tested every combination of indexes in WHERE clause without no effect.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) as `timestamp`, SUM(s200)             
FROM stats5 source FORCE INDEX (serverTimeAccount)
WHERE 
     ts BETWEEN '2019-09-02 00:00:00' 
     AND '2019-09-29 10:34:59'                 
     AND source.account IN (1723690123, 1480222913, 1671639327)               
     AND source.server IN (487724652, 392397498, 921318692, 106441609, 137383902, 680683224, 729228262, 922214594, 761074821, 479470850, 288343450, 135577161, 428962842, 957163996, 192914558, 199478874, 298000759, 223480773, 224694553, 237566801, 240310753, 254337807, 273124907, 278750532, 294148842, 318883354, 322363682, 327417460, 336685337, 337331656, 670931850, 355651511, 787115097, 392009278, 392881199, 397759361, 144389986, 592798480, 854341815, 328415864, 430494657, 307866045, 440682156, 306294551, 446693852, 844464756, 379723299, 467711965, 470696737, 488880834, 494323647, 752727683, 532918106, 560212922, 568296469, 573182806, 698126022, 725592130, 736377314, 766114409, 463650150, 954723866, 449604475, 280490587, 231945023, 277636832, 844801431, 802497771, 808342479, 817041331, 992853256, 829960029, 830570018, 844574059, 850431558, 330894179, 582465085, 451109569, 872789116, 877284014, 882013923, 592715900, 896008142, 902812495, 956349752, 972422365, 988219613, 990905698, 306433498, 341791382, 111447589)             
GROUP BY source.ts;
```

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EXPLAIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "1390775.41"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "sort_cost": "579376.00"
      },
      "table": {
        "table_name": "source",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "timeAccountServer",
          "accountTime",
          "timeServer",
          "accountServerTime",
          "timeServerAccount",
          "accountTimeServer",
          "serverAccountTime",
          "serverTimeAccount"
        ],
        "key": "serverAccountTime",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "server",
          "account",
          "ts"
        ],
        "key_length": "14",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 579376,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 579376,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "index_condition": "((`stats`.`source`.`ts` between '2020-01-02 00:00:00' and '2020-01-29 10:34:59') and (`stats`.`source`.`account` in (1723690123,1480222913,1671639327)) and (`stats`.`source`.`server` in (487724652,392397498,921318692,106441609,137383902,680683224,729228262,922214594,761074821,479470850,288343450,135577161,428962842,957163996,192914558,199478874,298000759,223480773,224694553,237566801,240310753,254337807,273124907,278750532,294148842,318883354,322363682,327417460,336685337,337331656,670931850,355651511,787115097,392009278,392881199,397759361,144389986,592798480,854341815,328415864,430494657,307866045,440682156,306294551,446693852,844464756,379723299,467711965,470696737,488880834,494323647,752727683,532918106,560212922,568296469,573182806,698126022,725592130,736377314,766114409,463650150,954723866,449604475,280490587,231945023,277636832,844801431,802497771,808342479,817041331,992853256,829960029,830570018,844574059,850431558,330894179,582465085,451109569,872789116,877284014,882013923,592715900,896008142,902812495,956349752,972422365,988219613,990905698,306433498,341791382,111447589)))",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "695524.21",
          "eval_cost": "115875.20",
          "prefix_cost": "811399.41",
          "data_read_per_join": "70M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "account",
          "server",
          "ts",
          "s200",
          "s2xx",
          "s301",
          "s302",
          "s3xx"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
} |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Table  | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------+------------------+
| stats5 | CREATE TABLE `stats5` (
  `account` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `server` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `s200` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `s2xx` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `s301` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `s302` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `s3xx` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `s403` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `s404` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `s4xx` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `s5xx` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hit` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `miss` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `updating` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `expired` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `empty` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `stale` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `other` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sizeHit` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sizeMiss` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sizeUpdt` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sizeExp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sizeStale` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sizeUnk` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `timeAccountServer` (`ts`,`account`,`server`),
  KEY `accountTime` (`account`,`ts`),
  KEY `timeServer` (`ts`,`server`),
  KEY `accountServerTime` (`account`,`server`,`ts`),
  KEY `timeServerAccount` (`ts`,`server`,`account`),
  KEY `accountTimeServer` (`account`,`ts`,`server`),
  KEY `serverAccountTime` (`server`,`account`,`ts`),
  KEY `serverTimeAccount` (`server`,`ts`,`account`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+--------+-----------------------------------------+
```

My version is 5.7.29-32, server with 192GB RAM

My config:

```
[mysqld]
user    = mysql
pid-file  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port    = 3306
basedir   = /usr
datadir   = /ssd/mysql
tmpdir    = /ssd/tmp
plugin_dir = /usr/lib/mysql/plugin
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
key_buffer_size    = 256M
max_allowed_packet  = 200M
thread_stack    = 256K
thread_cache_size       = 128
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
log-error               = /var/log/mysql/error.log
server-id   = 1
log_bin     = /ssd/mysql_info/binlog
expire_logs_days  = 3
max_binlog_size         = 1000M
binlog-format   = ROW
sync_binlog             = 10000
relay-log   = /ssd/mysql_info/relaylog
relay-log-info-file = /ssd/mysql_info/relay.info
max_connections        = 500
innodb_file_per_table=1
table_open_cache=1024
table_definition_cache=1024
innodb_read_io_threads=32
innodb_write_io_threads=32
innodb_io_capacity=20000
innodb_io_capacity_max=40000
innodb_buffer_pool_size=80G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=64
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_purge_threads=1
event_scheduler=ON
default_time_zone='+00:00'
super_read_only=on
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
binlog_cache_size=16M
innodb_log_file_size=5G
query_cache_limit=0
query_cache_type=0
```

Do you have any ideas how to speed up this query?

Output of explain:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                                                          | key           | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | source | NULL       | range | timeAccountServer,accountTime,timeServer,accountServerTime,timeServerAccount,accountTimeServer,serverAccountTime,serverTimeAccount | accountServerTime | 14      | NULL | 552041 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` would help for details about indexes

Comment: I've updated the post with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: What is the size in gigabytes of this table ? How many rows does the query return ? Can you give a full example of a slow query ie. with full WHERE clause for IN expressions and the number of rows returned ?

Comment: @pifor - table stats5 has 1386GB. Query returns 7.000 rows. I've updated query in the post with full WHERE clause.

Comment: My guess is that it is slow on first run because it has to read the data from disk to memory. What kind of disk configuration do you use?

Comment: Can you try to run the given query without any FORCE INDEX clause: how much time does it take ? Please post the output of `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON <full query>`.

Comment: The duration without FORCE INDEX is the same (around 3 minutes). I've update original post with EXPLAIN. Create temporary table for query without Group BY clause took almost whole time of 3 minutes.

Comment: it looks like GROUP BY operation is using disk: to avoid this try to set in the database session SORT_BUFFER_SIZE to 2GB with `set sort_buffer_size=2*1024*1024*1024;`

Comment: create index on ts,account,server,s200

Comment: @pifor - sort_buffer_size has no effect on query duration

Comment: @pifor - Don't increase the `sort_buffer_size` above 1% of RAM -- Some day you will have two big selects running, and mysqld will run out of RAM.  This leads to swapping (very slow) or a crash (out of swap space).

Answer (score 1):

**Lack of PK**

You have no explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.  Because `ts` is nullable, it has not been used as the PK.  If it is never NULL, making that change would help. 
 Depending on what version you are using, either of these would make that query run faster:

```
PRIMARY KEY(account, server, ts)
PRIMARY KEY(server, account, ts)
```

Once you add a PK, the `UNIQUE` index should be dropped or at least made into `INDEX`.

**Don't FORCE**

`FORCE INDEX` is not a viable solution; the real solution is to cluster the data so that *only* the necessary rows are touched.

**Optimal index**

Furthermore, all 4 columns need to be in the same BTree.  Hence, either of these should work well (without any `FORCE`):

```
INDEX(account, server, ts, s200)
INDEX(server, account, ts, s200)
```

Caveat:  Only newer versions of MySQL/MariaDB will successfully "hop" through the index rather than plowing through multiple `INs` plus a date range.  If it is a good version; this suggestion is probably the best.

**Miscellany**

Meanwhile, you are trying a lot of indexes; on a billion rows, this is costly in disk space and `INSERT` speed.  Are there other queries you need to optimize?  It would be better to work with all the queries at the same time; there may need to be compromises.

Meanwhile, drop any indexes that are a prefix of this one.

How many rows are there before the SUMming?  After the `GROUP BY`?

Meanwhile, here is another tool for judging indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Another tip:  Do you really need `BIGINT`, which takes 8 bytes or `INT` (4 bytes) for those other columns?  Shrinking the table size helps performance some.

`GROUP BY` a datetime _to the seconds seems very strange.  Are there many rows for each second?  If not, it *may* be better to use

```
INDEX(ts, account, server, s200)
```

(or flip the middle two).  The 4-col indexes I am suggesting are "covering", which *may* give a significant performance boost.

Comment: he is on MySQL 5.7 and it seems he needs to create index on (ts,account,server,s200) to scan required date range and filter it without key lookups

Comment: @Nikita - Some versions have an optimizer that will hop through the `IN` values, then scan the `ts` values.  Depending on various statistics, this may be a lot faster, even after having to do a sort for the `GROUP BY`.  But I added another index choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your date strings to datetime, so that mysql doesn't need to convert each datetime to a string;

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) as `timestamp`,ts, SUM(s200)             
  FROM stats5 source 
  WHERE 
    source.ts
      BETWEEN str_to_date('2019-09-02 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
          AND str_to_date('2019-09-29 10:34:59','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
    AND (source.account,source.server) IN (
            (1723690123,487724652),
            (1723690123,392397498),
            (1723690123,921318692),
            (1723690123,106441609),
            (1723690123,137383902),
            (1723690123,680683224),
            (1723690123,729228262),
            (1723690123,922214594),
            (1723690123,761074821),
            (1723690123,479470850),
            (1723690123,288343450),
            (1723690123,135577161),
            (1723690123,428962842),
            (1723690123,957163996),
            (1723690123,192914558),
            (1723690123,199478874),
            (1723690123,298000759),
            (1723690123,223480773),
            (1723690123,224694553),
            (1723690123,237566801),
            (1723690123,240310753),
            (1723690123,254337807),
            (1723690123,273124907),
            (1723690123,278750532),
            (1723690123,294148842),
            (1723690123,318883354),
            (1723690123,322363682),
            (1723690123,327417460),
            (1723690123,336685337),
            (1723690123,337331656),
            (1723690123,670931850),
            (1723690123,355651511),
            (1723690123,787115097),
            (1723690123,392009278),
            (1723690123,392881199),
            (1723690123,397759361),
            (1723690123,144389986),
            (1723690123,592798480),
            (1723690123,854341815),
            (1723690123,328415864),
            (1723690123,430494657),
            (1723690123,307866045),
            (1723690123,440682156),
            (1723690123,306294551),
            (1723690123,446693852),
            (1723690123,844464756),
            (1723690123,379723299),
            (1723690123,467711965),
            (1723690123,470696737),
            (1723690123,488880834),
            (1723690123,494323647),
            (1723690123,752727683),
            (1723690123,532918106),
            (1723690123,560212922),
            (1723690123,568296469),
            (1723690123,573182806),
            (1723690123,698126022),
            (1723690123,725592130),
            (1723690123,736377314),
            (1723690123,766114409),
            (1723690123,463650150),
            (1723690123,954723866),
            (1723690123,449604475),
            (1723690123,280490587),
            (1723690123,231945023),
            (1723690123,277636832),
            (1723690123,844801431),
            (1723690123,802497771),
            (1723690123,808342479),
            (1723690123,817041331),
            (1723690123,992853256),
            (1723690123,829960029),
            (1723690123,830570018),
            (1723690123,844574059),
            (1723690123,850431558),
            (1723690123,330894179),
            (1723690123,582465085),
            (1723690123,451109569),
            (1723690123,872789116),
            (1723690123,877284014),
            (1723690123,882013923),
            (1723690123,592715900),
            (1723690123,896008142),
            (1723690123,902812495),
            (1723690123,956349752),
            (1723690123,972422365),
            (1723690123,988219613),
            (1723690123,990905698),
            (1723690123,306433498),
            (1723690123,341791382),
            (1723690123,111447589),
            (1480222913,487724652),
            (1480222913,392397498),
            (1480222913,921318692),
            (1480222913,106441609),
            (1480222913,137383902),
            (1480222913,680683224),
            (1480222913,729228262),
            (1480222913,922214594),
             (1480222913,761074821),
            (1480222913,479470850),
            (1480222913,288343450),
            (1480222913,135577161),
            (1480222913,428962842),
            (1480222913,957163996),
            (1480222913,192914558),
            (1480222913,199478874),
            (1480222913,298000759),
            (1480222913,223480773),
            (1480222913,224694553),
            (1480222913,237566801),
            (1480222913,240310753),
            (1480222913,254337807),
            (1480222913,273124907),
            (1480222913,278750532),
            (1480222913,294148842),
            (1480222913,318883354),
            (1480222913,322363682),
            (1480222913,327417460),
            (1480222913,336685337),
            (1480222913,337331656),
            (1480222913,670931850),
            (1480222913,355651511),
            (1480222913,787115097),
            (1480222913,392009278),
            (1480222913,392881199),
            (1480222913,397759361),
            (1480222913,144389986),
            (1480222913,592798480),
            (1480222913,854341815),
            (1480222913,328415864),
            (1480222913,430494657),
            (1480222913,307866045),
            (1480222913,440682156),
            (1480222913,306294551),
            (1480222913,446693852),
            (1480222913,844464756),
            (1480222913,379723299),
            (1480222913,467711965),
            (1480222913,470696737),
            (1480222913,488880834),
            (1480222913,494323647),
            (1480222913,752727683),
            (1480222913,532918106),
            (1480222913,560212922),
            (1480222913,568296469),
            (1480222913,573182806),
            (1480222913,698126022),
            (1480222913,725592130),
            (1480222913,736377314),
            (1480222913,766114409),
            (1480222913,463650150),
            (1480222913,954723866),
            (1480222913,449604475),
            (1480222913,280490587),
            (1480222913,231945023),
            (1480222913,277636832),
            (1480222913,844801431),
            (1480222913,802497771),
            (1480222913,808342479),
            (1480222913,817041331),
            (1480222913,992853256),
            (1480222913,829960029),
            (1480222913,830570018),
            (1480222913,844574059),
            (1480222913,850431558),
            (1480222913,330894179),
            (1480222913,582465085),
            (1480222913,451109569),
            (1480222913,872789116),
            (1480222913,877284014),
            (1480222913,882013923),
            (1480222913,592715900),
            (1480222913,896008142),
            (1480222913,902812495),
            (1480222913,956349752),
            (1480222913,972422365),
            (1480222913,988219613),
            (1480222913,990905698),
            (1480222913,306433498),
            (1480222913,341791382),
            (1480222913,111447589),
            (1671639327,487724652),
            (1671639327,392397498),
            (1671639327,921318692),
            (1671639327,106441609),
            (1671639327,137383902),
            (1671639327,680683224),
            (1671639327,729228262),
            (1671639327,922214594),
            (1671639327,761074821),
            (1671639327,479470850),
            (1671639327,288343450),
            (1671639327,135577161),
            (1671639327,428962842),
            (1671639327,957163996),
            (1671639327,192914558),
            (1671639327,199478874),
            (1671639327,298000759),
            (1671639327,223480773),
            (1671639327,224694553),
            (1671639327,237566801),
            (1671639327,240310753),
            (1671639327,254337807),
            (1671639327,273124907),
            (1671639327,278750532),
            (1671639327,294148842),
            (1671639327,318883354),
            (1671639327,322363682),
            (1671639327,327417460),
            (1671639327,336685337),
            (1671639327,337331656),
            (1671639327,670931850),
            (1671639327,355651511),
            (1671639327,787115097),
            (1671639327,392009278),
            (1671639327,392881199),
            (1671639327,397759361),
            (1671639327,144389986),
            (1671639327,592798480),
            (1671639327,854341815),
            (1671639327,328415864),
            (1671639327,430494657),
            (1671639327,307866045),
            (1671639327,440682156),
            (1671639327,306294551),
            (1671639327,446693852),
            (1671639327,844464756),
            (1671639327,379723299),
            (1671639327,467711965),
            (1671639327,470696737),
            (1671639327,488880834),
            (1671639327,494323647),
            (1671639327,752727683),
            (1671639327,532918106),
            (1671639327,560212922),
            (1671639327,568296469),
            (1671639327,573182806),
            (1671639327,698126022),
            (1671639327,725592130),
            (1671639327,736377314),
            (1671639327,766114409),
            (1671639327,463650150),
            (1671639327,954723866),
            (1671639327,449604475),
            (1671639327,280490587),
            (1671639327,231945023),
            (1671639327,277636832),
            (1671639327,844801431),
            (1671639327,802497771),
            (1671639327,808342479),
            (1671639327,817041331),
            (1671639327,992853256),
            (1671639327,829960029),
            (1671639327,830570018),
            (1671639327,844574059),
            (1671639327,850431558),
            (1671639327,330894179),
            (1671639327,582465085),
            (1671639327,451109569),
            (1671639327,872789116),
            (1671639327,877284014),
            (1671639327,882013923),
            (1671639327,592715900),
            (1671639327,896008142),
            (1671639327,902812495),
            (1671639327,956349752),
            (1671639327,972422365),
            (1671639327,988219613),
            (1671639327,990905698),
            (1671639327,306433498),
            (1671639327,341791382),
            (1671639327,111447589)
        )             
  GROUP BY source.ts;
```

The change of the "IN" may allow MySQL to use one of your many indices.

Comment: str_to_date has no effect on duration

Comment: I forgot to remove the "force index".  Also, the "IN" for account and server needs optimization.  Give me a minute.

Comment: I've updated the full query in the original post. IMHO I can't use the syntax of "IN" that you suggest. I'm getting "Operand should contain 2 column(s)" error.

Comment: You need to specify each possible combination of account an server, as in "IN ((A1,S1),(A1,S2),(A1,S3),(A2,S1),....)

Comment: That's a "row constructor".  It is grossly inefficient until MySQL 5.7, where it is sometimes efficient.  See my second answer.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - `str_to_date()` should not be necessary -- the string given is immediately comparable to a `DATETIME`.

Comment: You're saying MySQL stores a DATETIME as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query, please

```
SELECT ts, SUM(s200)             
FROM stats5 source 
WHERE 
     ts BETWEEN '2019-09-02 00:00:00' 
     AND '2019-09-29 10:34:59'                 
     AND source.account IN (1723690123, 1480222913, 1671639327)               
     AND source.server IN (487724652, 392397498, 921318692, 106441609, 137383902, 680683224, 729228262, 922214594, 761074821, 479470850, 288343450, 135577161, 428962842, 957163996, 192914558, 199478874, 298000759, 223480773, 224694553, 237566801, 240310753, 254337807, 273124907, 278750532, 294148842, 318883354, 322363682, 327417460, 336685337, 337331656, 670931850, 355651511, 787115097, 392009278, 392881199, 397759361, 144389986, 592798480, 854341815, 328415864, 430494657, 307866045, 440682156, 306294551, 446693852, 844464756, 379723299, 467711965, 470696737, 488880834, 494323647, 752727683, 532918106, 560212922, 568296469, 573182806, 698126022, 725592130, 736377314, 766114409, 463650150, 954723866, 449604475, 280490587, 231945023, 277636832, 844801431, 802497771, 808342479, 817041331, 992853256, 829960029, 830570018, 844574059, 850431558, 330894179, 582465085, 451109569, 872789116, 877284014, 882013923, 592715900, 896008142, 902812495, 956349752, 972422365, 988219613, 990905698, 306433498, 341791382, 111447589)             
GROUP BY source.ts;
```

and let us know how long it takes and post TEXT results of EXPLAIN (this query), please.

WHY do you NOT have a PRIMARY KEY?  You have NO Clustered Index when you have NO Primary Key.

Comment: I' ve added output of explain to your query at the end of the original post. Query takes around 3 minutes. I'm not sure about primary key and clustered index. Do you suggest to try add it?

Comment: @MarekFiala Some moderator 'edited' what I was asking you to try.  Needless to say, they did not include all the changes I had suggested.  When you want to work with me, view my profile, Network profile and consider downloading our free Utility Scripts to improve performance of your instance.

Comment: @MarekFiala  First to the moderator - what you did for formatting was OK - you left nothing out - my humble apologies.  Marek, change  the FROM stats5 source, line to FROM stats5 source FORCE INDEX (timeAccountServer)    without the ending comma and get the new timing, please and post the new EXPLAIN.

Comment: @MarekFiala About the PRIMARY KEY, we need to talk. You may already have a candidate.

Comment: @MarekFiala Could you post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE source; please.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, but a comment about row constructors in IN)

5.7.3 changelog says

> The optimizer now is able to apply the range scan access method to
>   queries of this form:
>
> SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE ( col_1, col_2 ) IN (( 'a', 'b' ), ( 'c', 'd'
>   ));
>
> Previously, for range scans to be used it was necessary for the query
>   to be written as:
>
> SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE ( col_1 = 'a' AND col_2 = 'b' ) OR ( col_1 =
>   'c' AND col_2 = 'd' );
>
> For the optimizer to use a range scan, queries must satisfy these
>   conditions:
>
> - Only IN predicates can be used, not NOT IN.
> - There may only be column references in the row constructor on the IN predicate's left hand side.
> - There must be more than one row constructor on the IN predicate's right hand side.
> - Row constructors on the IN predicate's right hand side must contain only runtime constants, which are either literals or local
>     column references that are bound to constants during execution.
>
> EXPLAIN output for applicable queries will change from full table or
>   index scan to range scan. Changes are also visible by checking the
>   values of the Handler_read_first, Handler_read_key, and
>   Handler_read_next status variables.

A tip on using Handler values to get more insight into what is going on:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts